# Does declaring font-size twice on an element have an effect?

Tags: css

I was given a bunch of CSS in which many elements have things declared twice per selector, such as:

```
.whatever {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

The reasoning I was given (second hand) was that the 1.4rem is relative to the other font-size (or something).  Regardless of the reasoning: **"can it possibly have any effect?"**  I'd be surprised to see something like this in the CSS standard. **Yes**, it may be valid to have both, but I'd expect the second declaration to completely override the first, not to be impacted by it

Comment: *but I'd expect the second declaration to completely override the first,* --> this is exaclty what will happen. Only one property is considered by the browser before even looking at its value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does override it. In this case the second declaration will take precedence.

Answer (score 3):

The second declaration will override the first, except in old browsers that didn't support the `rem` unit, which is a relatively modern invention. In those browsers, the 16px *fallback* declaration will be used.

Note that the order here is important. The fallback declaration must precede the desired declaration.

This pattern is indeed described in the CSS 2.2 spec under [4.3.8 Unsupported Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#unsupported-values) where it gives this example:

```
h3 {
  display: inline;
  display: run-in;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, yes it will override the style. The second declaration will take effect to the class element. It will be different case when you have styling both in #id, .class or inline style.